# How to understanding the mouse strains name and differences in mouse strains used in biology

Tags: zoology, animal-models, mouse

I am currently working with various mouse strains in my biological research and I am encountering some confusion regarding their nomenclature and differences. I understand that the different names indicate different origins, but I am finding it difficult to decipher the specific meanings behind these names.

For instance, I frequently come across the strain C57BL/6JN. It seems that C57BL represents a common mouse strain, but I am unsure about the meaning of the slash and the 6JN. Could someone kindly elaborate on this?

Additionally, I have seen the name C57BL/6NJ referenced in some literature. Is this the same strain as C57BL/6JN, or do they possess certain distinct characteristics? I would appreciate any clarification or guidance on this matter. Thank you!

Regrads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There once was a mouse numbered "57". Someone used that mouse to make a bunch of inbred lines. One of those lines, number 6, survived well. It had a black coat.

This is the C57, black, line number 6, or C57BL/6, also called "black 6". Remember that inbreeding is typically "bad", so it takes a lot of tries to make an inbred mouse line; most turn out to have fatal diseases or poor reproduction.

The original line was and is maintained by Jackson Labs, we call that strain J. NIH started maintaining a line from that same stock. We call that strain N or 6N; sometimes JN because it started as J. These are all inbred lines so they "should" be identical, but in practice mutations happen and genetic drift can occur; this is mitigated by back-crossing within the inbred line but Jackson wasn't back crossing theirs with NIH and vice versa, so it's proper to consider them separate lines.

Jackson Labs also now has taken the NIH strain and maintained it to sell:

https://www.jax.org/strain/005304

They call this C57BL/6NJ: the 6N strain now back at J.

Other people have taken and bred lines from these strains so there are numerous others, most are less significant since they're not mass produced commercially. Jackson Labs has really good documentation on their mouse lines including known SNPs between lines, if you're ever curious I'd start there and see what they have documented before looking for other sources.

Some other references:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C57BL/6

https://www.jax.org/strain/000664

Bryant, C. D. (2011). The blessings and curses of C57BL/6 substrains in mouse genetic studies. Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences, 1245, 31.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that's awesome! Can I ask an additional question to confirm my understanding? Taking C57BL/6NJ and C57BL/6JN as examples, first, Jackson Labs obtained a well-characterized mouse strain C57BL/6J through inbreeding up to the sixth generation. Then, NIH acquired and maintained this strain, so the strain maintained by NIH is referred to as C57BL/6N or C57BL/6JN. C57BL/6N and C57BL/6J have the same genetic background (except for genetic drift and new mutations that may occur after separation).

Comment: Afterwards, Jackson Labs obtained C57BL/6N (also known as C57BL/6JN) from NIH and commercially sells these mice, which are referred to as C57BL/6NJ

Comment: @zhang Nothing about "6 generations". Dozens of generations. 6 is not the generation number, it's one of several lines started from the same mouse.

Comment: @zhang inbreeding typically goes on for 20+ generations to fix the genetic lines. The 6 refers to the original line - it'll be 6th attempt or 6th mouse pairing they tried to do this to, or something similar. Nothing to do with generations.